# Using list an Linq in c#

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a list for testin my linq concept i m having trouble to make a list name booklist in class Books.

'

```
Public class Books
{
    string Author ="auth";
    string Title="title";
    string Publisher ="publisher";
    Int Year=2008;
    List<Books> booklist = new List<Books>
    { 
        Title="Learning c#",
        Author="Jesse",
        Publisher="o reilly",
        Year =2008
    },
}
```

Comment: So whats going wrong ?

Comment: _"i m having trouble..."_ ..to understand your question. Read here at _"following collection initializer uses object initializers to initialize objects of the Cat class"_: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: I having trouble as i am getting error that Author is not defined in Collection.Generics.List please i want complete code how to initialise list items

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the list with instances of Book, not just the properties of Book - also use the name Book for a class representing a Book rather than 'Books' which implies a collection of some sort:

```
List<Book> booklist = new List<Book>{ 
    new Book 
    {
        Title="Learning c#",
        Author="Jesse",
        Publisher="o reilly",
        Year =2008}
    },
    new Book 
    {
        Title="Another book",
        Author="Jesse",
        Publisher="o reilly",
        Year =2008}
    },    
}
```

Comment: You should mention that Book is a better name for the Books class and then use it consistently ;)

Comment: Indeed - didn't even see that @Ralf :)

Answer (score 1):

Define class like this

```
public class Book
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Publisher{get;set;}
    public int Year{get;set;}
}
```

Make list like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book> { new Book { Author = "author1", Title = "title1", Publisher = "pub1", Year = 2015 },
                                                new Book { Author = "author2", Title = "title2", Publisher = "pub2", Year = 2015 } };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Books
        {
            public string Author { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Publisher { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
        }
```

Create list in another class

```
Books bk = new Books();
            bk.Title="Learning c#";
            bk.Author="Jesse";
            bk.Publisher="o reilly";
            bk.Year =2008;

            List<Books> booklist = new List<Books>();

            booklist.Add(bk);
```